Set DataValidation in a list of columns at once
I'm trying to rewrite some old VBA code to Office Script.
One of the steps is to set data validation on several columns.
With the script I am able to loop all columns of a named table.
So my idea was to use a switch on the column names to set the related data validation.
So far so good - but: all defined rules set in the ForEach loop are somehow not done when calling the setRule() but all columns do have afterwards the last defined rule (here: the one from column name "Lagerstatus".
Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!
Best regeards,
Pascal
Code snippet:
    let sbOrderTable = workbook.getTable("mainOrderTable");
    const errorAlertStype = ExcelScript.DataValidationAlertStyle.stop;

    sbOrderTable.getColumns().forEach(column => {
        let columnName = column.getName();
        let errorMessage = "Nur Einträge aus dem PullDown-Menü sind zulässig";
        let dataValidation: ExcelScript.DataValidation;
        
        dataValidation = column.getRange().getDataValidation();
        dataValidation.clear();
        dataValidation.setIgnoreBlanks(true);
        dataValidation.setPrompt({ showPrompt: false, title: "", message: "" });
        dataValidation.setErrorAlert({ showAlert: true, title: columnName, message: errorMessage, style: errorAlertStype });

        switch (columnName) {
            case "Lieferant":
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF_SYNC!$D$6:$D$1048576" } });
            case "Hersteller":
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF_SYNC!$B$6:$B$1048576" } }); 1
            case "Ersatzteil":
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF!$A$6:$A$7" } });
            case "Bestell Index":
                //errorMessage = "Ungültiger Bestell-Index gemäss Referenz";
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: false, source: "=REF_IDX!$A$6:$A$1048576" } });
            case "Bestellt von":
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF_SYNC!$A$6:$A$1048576" } });
            case "Bestellstatus":
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF!$B$6:$B$1048576" } });
            case "Lagerstatus":
                dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF!$B$6:$B$1048576" } });
        }
    });


Pls add break for each case clause.
switch (columnName) {
        case "Lieferant":
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF_SYNC!$D$6:$D$1048576" } });
            break;
        case "Hersteller":
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF_SYNC!$B$6:$B$1048576" } });
            break;
        case "Ersatzteil":
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF!$A$6:$A$7" } });
            break;
        case "Bestell Index":
            //errorMessage = "Ungültiger Bestell-Index gemäss Referenz";
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: false, source: "=REF_IDX!$A$6:$A$1048576" } });
            break;
        case "Bestellt von":
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF_SYNC!$A$6:$A$1048576" } });
            break;
        case "Bestellstatus":
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF!$B$6:$B$1048576" } });
            break;
        case "Lagerstatus":
            dataValidation.setRule({ list: { inCellDropDown: true, source: "=REF!$B$6:$B$1048576" } });
            break;
        default:
            // if non-macthing above
    }


A simple demo of switch / case / break.
const fruit = "banana";

switch (fruit) {
  case "apple":
    console.log("Apple selected");
  case "banana":
    console.log("Banana selected");
  case "grape":
    console.log("Grape selected");
  default:
    console.log("Unknown fruit");
}

You might expect the output to be Banana selected. However, the actual output is as follows. Since there's no break, after the "banana" case matches, the code continues executing the "grape" and "default" cases as well, causing unintended behavior.
Output in console:
Banana selected
Grape selected
Unknown fruit

Back to your script, there are 7 case clauses without break. For the first column ("Lieferant"), the script applies the data validation rules 7 times, with the last rule overwriting the previous ones.

thx taller - my VB time gets me from time to time...

I completely understand that there are significant differences between VBA and Office Scripts.
